# RegEx to add restrict space in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/\$|\#|\%|\<|\>|\&|\^|\&|\*|\'|\,/
```

This is the regular expression to restrict special charterers. I just wanted to add white space RegEx along with the current expression.

Comment: `/\$|\#|\%|\<|\>|\&|\^|\&|\*|\'|\,|\s/`

Comment: You want to allow or don't want to allow

Comment: `/[$#%<>&^*',\s]/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it:

```
/[$#%<>&^*',\s]/
```

Comment: there is a problem. it is allowing spaces at the end and beginning

Comment: @Akhil, no, it doesn't. Check for calling `trim` before regex check.

Comment: how to restrict length with this expression

Comment: can you please provide expression completely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\$|\#|\%|\<|\>|\&|\^|\&|\*|\'|\,|\s/
```

Comment: still its allowing spaces.

Comment: There's an unwanted Space before '\s'.

Comment: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) & paste this expression & validate